# How to test the blackberry application in blackberry mobile

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

I created one blackberry application, and i tested in blackberry simulator, now i need test in blackberry mobile phone , can u please tell me the process for creating setup file and how to install in the black berry phone...

Thanking you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is :
- Copy all jad, jar, cod file to a temporary folder
- rename cod file to zip file
- extract the content of the zip file to the temporary folder
- copy the temporary folder to the blackberry SD card
- in the BB go to home menu -> media -> explore
- browse to where you copy the temporary folder
- run the JAD file

No Upload/download required.

Answer (score 2):

javaloader -usb load  on your console :-)

Comment: This is the easiest, most scriptable way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ways are:

First... Generate ALX file and install that using Blackberry Desktop Manager.
Second... Publish both .JAD and .COD and make a link to de first. Download and install it over the air with Blackberry Browser...

Of course, thats after signed the COD with RIM Signed Keys.